# Application Closes on Exception in Debug Mode

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, debugging

I have a global exception handler hooked up to Application.ThreadingException and this works fine when the application is not being debugged.

I have noticed several times that in debug my application closes without warning and without the debugger stopping on the error.  I have thought this might be connected to my Global Exception Handler but it is not.

I appear to be getting more an more cases on errors that are caught by the GEH that result in the app closing while in debug mode.  I have no idea why this is happening but it is very annoying as the only way to debug this is to work out somewhere in the code to put a breakpoint and single step until the crash.

Is it possible I turned some option off in VS2010? Any help and guidance would be most appreciated.

**EDIT**  I can confirm that I have CLR Exceptions checked As Break on Exception when User Unhandled

Comment: Pretty unclear what you did to make this happen.  Code required.  I supposed you'll want to use Debugger.IsAttached to disable whatever you do now.

Comment: Code would be difficult I think - the app has over 100,000 lines and I would not know where to start.  I will look at Debugger.IsAttached - thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the [UnhandledExceptionMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms157905.aspx) of your Application to CatchException so your global exception handler will always be notified about exceptions.

Comment: That's what is already happening.  He wants the opposite behavior, the handler should *not* be notified when the debugger is attached.  So that the Exception Assistant kicks in instead of the app aborting.